# .htaccess redirect not working as expected

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect the following uris: `search`, `search/acquia-search` , `search/acquia-search/`, `search/site` or `search/site/` to the homepage which is `/`. Here is my rewrite rule.

`RewriteRule ^(search|search/acquia-search|search/site)(?!.*) / [R=301,L]`

In the above rule I am trying to match those uris and ensure that they're not followed by anything using the negative lookahead.

here is my full .htaccess http://pastebin.com/stNgzfnD

what am I doing wrong?

Edit: The above did not work but the following did:

`RewriteRule ^(search|search/acquia-search|search/site)/?$ / [L,R,NC]`

Answer (score 0):

`(?!.*)` negative lookahead doesn't make any sense since **it will always fail the regex**.

Better use this regex:

```
RewriteRule ^search(/(acquia-search|site/?)?$ / [L,R,NC]
```